# how to iterate through a table using node and cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, cheerio

All day todo I've been working on this web scraper that pulls the date and the sunset time from [sunrise-sunset.org](https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=portland%20oregon&year=2022&month=11#calendar)

Iv managed to get it to scrape and display the first day and time in the table but I cant find out how to iterate through the table while using node, axios, and cheerio since im pretty new to all three.

my JSON only has one object but im trying to find out how to iterate through the table so I can have every table row as its own object. for example

---

> ```
> [
>   {
>    "day": "Tue, Nov 1",
>    "time": "5:59:57 pm"
>   }
>   {
>    "day": "Tue, Nov 2",
>    "time": "5:55:37 pm"
>   }
>   {
>    "day": "Tue, Nov 2",
>    "time": "5:42:47 pm"
>   }
> ]
> ```

---

This is my code so far that has resulted in pulling the first day and time from the website.

---

```
app.get('/results', function (req, res) {
        axios(url)
            .then(response => {
                const html = response.data
                const $ = cheerio.load(html)
                const days = []
    
                $('#month', html).each(function () {
                    const day = $('.number', '.day').prop('innerText')
                    const time = $('.sunset', '.day').prop('innerText')
                    days.push({
                        day,
                        time
                    })
                })
                res.json(days)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    })
```

---

I then display the results in an empty div with this code

---

```
const feedDisplay = document.querySelector('#feed')

fetch('http://localhost:8000/results')
    .then(response => { return response.json() })
    // .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(data => {
        data.forEach(daysaray => {
            const dayItem = `<div><h3>` + daysaray.day +`</h3><p>` + daysaray.time +`</div>`
            feedDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", dayItem)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

---

**EDIT**

This is the HTML of the table I'm trying to scrape

```
<table id="month">
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<col>
<tbody><tr class="headers">
<th rowspan="2">Day</th>
<th rowspan="2">Twilight start</th>
<th rowspan="2">Sunrise</th>
<th rowspan="2">Sunset</th>
<th rowspan="2">Twilight end</th>
<th rowspan="2">Day length</th>
<th rowspan="2">Solar noon</th>
<th colspan="2">Nautical twilight</th>
<th colspan="2">Astronomical twilight</th>
</tr>
<tr class="headers">
<th>Start</th>
<th>End</th>
<th>Start</th>
<th>End</th>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-01">
<th><span class="number">Tue, Nov 1</span></th>
<td>7:19:52 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-01 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:49:10 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-01 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">5:59:22 pm</span></td>
<td>6:28:40 pm</td>
<td>10:10:12</td>
<td>12:54:16 pm</td>
<td>6:44 am</td>
<td>7:03 pm</td>
<td>6:10 am</td>
<td>7:38 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-02">
<th><span class="number">Wed, Nov 2</span></th>
<td>7:21:11 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-02 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:50:33 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-02 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">5:57:57 pm</span></td>
<td>6:27:19 pm</td>
<td>10:07:24</td>
<td>12:54:15 pm</td>
<td>6:46 am</td>
<td>7:02 pm</td>
<td>6:11 am</td>
<td>7:36 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-03">
<th><span class="number">Thu, Nov 3</span></th>
<td>7:22:30 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-03 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:51:57 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-03 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">5:56:33 pm</span></td>
<td>6:26:00 pm</td>
<td>10:04:36</td>
<td>12:54:15 pm</td>
<td>6:47 am</td>
<td>7:01 pm</td>
<td>6:12 am</td>
<td>7:35 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-04">
<th><span class="number">Fri, Nov 4</span></th>
<td>7:23:49 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-04 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:53:21 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-04 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">5:55:11 pm</span></td>
<td>6:24:42 pm</td>
<td>10:01:50</td>
<td>12:54:16 pm</td>
<td>6:48 am</td>
<td>6:59 pm</td>
<td>6:14 am</td>
<td>7:34 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-05">
<th><span class="number">Sat, Nov 5</span></th>
<td>7:25:08 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-05 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:54:45 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-05 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">5:53:50 pm</span></td>
<td>6:23:27 pm</td>
<td>09:59:05</td>
<td>12:54:17 pm</td>
<td>6:49 am</td>
<td>6:58 pm</td>
<td>6:15 am</td>
<td>7:33 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-06">
<th><span class="number">Sun, Nov 6</span></th>
<td>6:26:27 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-06 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">6:56:09 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-06 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:52:31 pm</span></td>
<td>5:22:12 pm</td>
<td>09:56:22</td>
<td>11:54:20 am</td>
<td>5:51 am</td>
<td>5:57 pm</td>
<td>5:16 am</td>
<td>6:32 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-07">
<th><span class="number">Mon, Nov 7</span></th>
<td>6:27:46 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-07 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">6:57:32 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-07 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:51:14 pm</span></td>
<td>5:21:00 pm</td>
<td>09:53:42</td>
<td>11:54:23 am</td>
<td>5:52 am</td>
<td>5:56 pm</td>
<td>5:17 am</td>
<td>6:31 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-08">
<th><span class="number">Tue, Nov 8</span></th>
<td>6:29:05 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-08 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">6:58:56 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-08 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:49:59 pm</span></td>
<td>5:19:49 pm</td>
<td>09:51:03</td>
<td>11:54:27 am</td>
<td>5:53 am</td>
<td>5:55 pm</td>
<td>5:18 am</td>
<td>6:29 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-09">
<th><span class="number">Wed, Nov 9</span></th>
<td>6:30:24 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-09 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:00:20 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-09 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:48:45 pm</span></td>
<td>5:18:41 pm</td>
<td>09:48:25</td>
<td>11:54:32 am</td>
<td>5:54 am</td>
<td>5:54 pm</td>
<td>5:20 am</td>
<td>6:28 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-10">
<th><span class="number">Thu, Nov 10</span></th>
<td>6:31:42 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-10 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:01:43 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-10 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:47:33 pm</span></td>
<td>5:17:34 pm</td>
<td>09:45:50</td>
<td>11:54:38 am</td>
<td>5:56 am</td>
<td>5:53 pm</td>
<td>5:21 am</td>
<td>6:27 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-11">
<th><span class="number">Fri, Nov 11</span></th>
<td>6:33:01 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-11 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:03:07 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-11 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:46:23 pm</span></td>
<td>5:16:29 pm</td>
<td>09:43:16</td>
<td>11:54:45 am</td>
<td>5:57 am</td>
<td>5:52 pm</td>
<td>5:22 am</td>
<td>6:26 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-12">
<th><span class="number">Sat, Nov 12</span></th>
<td>6:34:19 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-12 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:04:30 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-12 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:45:15 pm</span></td>
<td>5:15:26 pm</td>
<td>09:40:45</td>
<td>11:54:52 am</td>
<td>5:58 am</td>
<td>5:51 pm</td>
<td>5:23 am</td>
<td>6:25 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-13">
<th><span class="number">Sun, Nov 13</span></th>
<td>6:35:37 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-13 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:05:53 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-13 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:44:09 pm</span></td>
<td>5:14:25 pm</td>
<td>09:38:16</td>
<td>11:55:01 am</td>
<td>5:59 am</td>
<td>5:50 pm</td>
<td>5:24 am</td>
<td>6:25 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-14">
<th><span class="number">Mon, Nov 14</span></th>
<td>6:36:54 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-14 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:07:15 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-14 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:43:05 pm</span></td>
<td>5:13:26 pm</td>
<td>09:35:50</td>
<td>11:55:10 am</td>
<td>6:01 am</td>
<td>5:49 pm</td>
<td>5:26 am</td>
<td>6:24 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-15">
<th><span class="number">Tue, Nov 15</span></th>
<td>6:38:12 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-15 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:08:37 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-15 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:42:03 pm</span></td>
<td>5:12:28 pm</td>
<td>09:33:26</td>
<td>11:55:20 am</td>
<td>6:02 am</td>
<td>5:48 pm</td>
<td>5:27 am</td>
<td>6:23 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-16">
<th><span class="number">Wed, Nov 16</span></th>
<td>6:39:28 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-16 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:09:59 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-16 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:41:03 pm</span></td>
<td>5:11:34 pm</td>
<td>09:31:04</td>
<td>11:55:31 am</td>
<td>6:03 am</td>
<td>5:47 pm</td>
<td>5:28 am</td>
<td>6:22 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-17">
<th><span class="number">Thu, Nov 17</span></th>
<td>6:40:45 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-17 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:11:21 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-17 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:40:05 pm</span></td>
<td>5:10:41 pm</td>
<td>09:28:44</td>
<td>11:55:43 am</td>
<td>6:04 am</td>
<td>5:46 pm</td>
<td>5:29 am</td>
<td>6:21 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day today" rel="2022-11-18">
<th><span class="number">Fri, Nov 18</span></th>
<td>6:42:01 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-18 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:12:42 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-18 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:39:09 pm</span></td>
<td>5:09:50 pm</td>
<td>09:26:27</td>
<td>11:55:55 am</td>
<td>6:05 am</td>
<td>5:45 pm</td>
<td>5:30 am</td>
<td>6:21 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-19">
<th><span class="number">Sat, Nov 19</span></th>
<td>6:43:16 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-19 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:14:02 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-19 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:38:15 pm</span></td>
<td>5:09:01 pm</td>
<td>09:24:13</td>
<td>11:56:09 am</td>
<td>6:07 am</td>
<td>5:45 pm</td>
<td>5:31 am</td>
<td>6:20 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-20">
<th><span class="number">Sun, Nov 20</span></th>
<td>6:44:31 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-20 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:15:22 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-20 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:37:24 pm</span></td>
<td>5:08:15 pm</td>
<td>09:22:02</td>
<td>11:56:23 am</td>
<td>6:08 am</td>
<td>5:44 pm</td>
<td>5:33 am</td>
<td>6:19 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-21">
<th><span class="number">Mon, Nov 21</span></th>
<td>6:45:45 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-21 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:16:41 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-21 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:36:35 pm</span></td>
<td>5:07:31 pm</td>
<td>09:19:54</td>
<td>11:56:38 am</td>
<td>6:09 am</td>
<td>5:43 pm</td>
<td>5:34 am</td>
<td>6:19 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-22">
<th><span class="number">Tue, Nov 22</span></th>
<td>6:46:58 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-22 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:17:59 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-22 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:35:48 pm</span></td>
<td>5:06:49 pm</td>
<td>09:17:49</td>
<td>11:56:54 am</td>
<td>6:10 am</td>
<td>5:43 pm</td>
<td>5:35 am</td>
<td>6:18 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-23">
<th><span class="number">Wed, Nov 23</span></th>
<td>6:48:11 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-23 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:19:17 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-23 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:35:04 pm</span></td>
<td>5:06:10 pm</td>
<td>09:15:47</td>
<td>11:57:10 am</td>
<td>6:11 am</td>
<td>5:42 pm</td>
<td>5:36 am</td>
<td>6:18 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-24">
<th><span class="number">Thu, Nov 24</span></th>
<td>6:49:23 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-24 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:20:34 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-24 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:34:22 pm</span></td>
<td>5:05:32 pm</td>
<td>09:13:48</td>
<td>11:57:28 am</td>
<td>6:12 am</td>
<td>5:42 pm</td>
<td>5:37 am</td>
<td>6:17 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-25">
<th><span class="number">Fri, Nov 25</span></th>
<td>6:50:34 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-25 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:21:50 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-25 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:33:42 pm</span></td>
<td>5:04:57 pm</td>
<td>09:11:52</td>
<td>11:57:46 am</td>
<td>6:13 am</td>
<td>5:41 pm</td>
<td>5:38 am</td>
<td>6:17 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-26">
<th><span class="number">Sat, Nov 26</span></th>
<td>6:51:45 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-26 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:23:05 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-26 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:33:05 pm</span></td>
<td>5:04:25 pm</td>
<td>09:10:00</td>
<td>11:58:05 am</td>
<td>6:15 am</td>
<td>5:41 pm</td>
<td>5:39 am</td>
<td>6:16 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-27">
<th><span class="number">Sun, Nov 27</span></th>
<td>6:52:54 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-27 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:24:19 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-27 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:32:30 pm</span></td>
<td>5:03:55 pm</td>
<td>09:08:11</td>
<td>11:58:24 am</td>
<td>6:16 am</td>
<td>5:40 pm</td>
<td>5:40 am</td>
<td>6:16 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-28">
<th><span class="number">Mon, Nov 28</span></th>
<td>6:54:03 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-28 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:25:31 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-28 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:31:58 pm</span></td>
<td>5:03:27 pm</td>
<td>09:06:27</td>
<td>11:58:45 am</td>
<td>6:17 am</td>
<td>5:40 pm</td>
<td>5:41 am</td>
<td>6:15 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-29">
<th><span class="number">Tue, Nov 29</span></th>
<td>6:55:10 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-29 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:26:43 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-29 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:31:28 pm</span></td>
<td>5:03:02 pm</td>
<td>09:04:45</td>
<td>11:59:06 am</td>
<td>6:18 am</td>
<td>5:39 pm</td>
<td>5:42 am</td>
<td>6:15 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr class="day" rel="2022-11-30">
<th><span class="number">Wed, Nov 30</span></th>
<td>6:56:16 am</td>
<td><span class="sunrise" title="Sunrise time 2022-11-30 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA">7:27:54 am</span></td>
<td><span title="Sunset time 2022-11-30 in Portland, Multnomah County, Oregon, USA" class="sunset">4:31:01 pm</span></td>
<td>5:02:39 pm</td>
<td>09:03:07</td>
<td>11:59:27 am</td>
<td>6:19 am</td>
<td>5:39 pm</td>
<td>5:43 am</td>
<td>6:15 pm</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `$("some id").each` doesn't make much sense. Identifiers are supposed to be unique in a valid HTML document, so this says "select something guaranteed to be at most a single element, then iterate that single element". Sure, some pages abuse identifiers as classes so this is conceivably useful in rare invalid HTML cases, but that doesn't apply here.

Instead, try selecting `<tr>` rows as described in [Scraping all rows from table using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109537/scraping-all-rows-from-table-using-cheerio/69138324#69138324) and [Parse table from HTML with cheerio in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73509779/parse-table-from-html-with-cheerio-in-node/73614552#73614552), then loop (or map) over those:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://sunrise-sunset.org/search?location=portland%20oregon&year=2022&month=11#calendar";

axios.get(url).then(({data: html}) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const rows = [...$("#month tr.day")].map(e => ({
    day: $(e).find(".number").text().trim(),
    time: $(e).find(".sunset").text().trim(),
  }));
  console.log(rows);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew i was looping the wrong part but when I tried to loop anything else it just repeated the same values over and over. Your suggestion did exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That's probably because your child selectors in the loop weren't relative to the container row, but rather to the whole document. Using `$(e).find()` is specific to each row container, so you don't grab the first element over and over. Glad it worked out.